# Send raw hex and strings over sockets

Tags: python, sockets, hex

I'm trying to send data over sockets with Python to trigger IDS rules.

Some of the strings have to be strings i.e. `Hello World`

Some of the strings have to be strings with hex i.e. `Hello World\xff`

Some of the strings have to be only hex i.e. `\xff\xff\xff\xff`

I'm currently sending the data as such:

```py
@classmethod
def send(cls, hostname: str = "8.8.8.8", srcPort: int = 0, destPort: int = 8080,
         content: str = "", buffer_size: int = 1024):
    srcPort = int(srcPort)
    destPort = int(destPort)
    content = content.encode()
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    # Address might be in a TIME_WAIT status, ignore this
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    # Port might be in a TIME_WAIT status, ignore this
    # sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEPORT, 1)

    # Set the source port before sending
    sock.bind(("", srcPort))
    sock.connect((hostname, destPort))
    sock.sendall(content)
    # shutdown might be redundant/unnecessary (tells connected host that we're
    #                                          done sending data)
    sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
    while True:
        data = sock.recv(buffer_size)
        if len(data) == 0:
            break
    sock.close()
```

Assuming the value of content is the string `\xff\xff\xff\xff`.

I would want the data in the `pcap` file to read `ff ff ff ff`, but instead it reads:

`5c 78 66 66 5c 78 66 66 5c 78 66 66 5c 78 66 66` (via wireshark)

Which is a literal translation of the string.

However, I also want a string like `RemoteNC Control Password:`

To read as

`52 65 6d 6f 74 65 4e 43 20 43 6f 6e 74 72 6f 6c 20 50 61 73 73 77 6f 72 64 3a`

which it currently does.

How can I get both of these done, without having to know if a string is just a string, a combination of a string & hex, or just hex? Is it even possible?

Comment: How are *you* deciding which way something should be sent? Can you write code that does the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get both of these done, without having to know if a string is just a string, a combination of a string & hex, or just hex? Is it even possible?

The easiest way is standardize your inputs and outputs so that you don't need to guess or check. `pack` them into raw bytes and then `unpack` them on the other end.

Decide on a standard encoding that you'll use for the character set, for example UTF-8.

Comment: Like using the struct library? One issue with using a standard encoding is because the content is based on Snort rules, some of the content might be packet garbage that encodings like UTF-8 and ASCII can't encode/decode. Otherwise I would just encode the original content. I parse the rules file and convert content like `|FF FF FF FF|` and `RemoteNC Control Password|3A|` to the content shown in my post.

Comment: @LeshawnRice Is it necessary to do string conversion? Can everything just be handled as bytes?

Comment: The content of the rules is parsed out from a file, so without manually writing the content of every rule out in bytes I have to convert the string content into bytes at some point

Comment: @LeshawnRice there must be some specs that you can look up. Are there delimiters that indicate the beginning and end of a byte sequence? If you are implementing a parser based on public format then specifications should be available. If it's a proprietary format you'll have to reverse engineer the specs.

Comment: Yes, a byte sequence is indicated by pipes `|`

Comment: @LeshawnRice you can read byte by byte and then when you see a pipe, stop and convert it if necessary, then continue reading until you reach the end of data

Comment: would you be able to give me minimal example of what you mean?